# Return specific object from a JSON object array

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-filters

Here is what my services.js looks like:

```
    var app = angular.module('starter.services', [])


    .factory('Studies',function($http,$filter){
        var studies = [];
        $http.get("studies.json").success(
                function(data){
                    //studies = data;
                    angular.copy(data, studies);
                }
            );
        single_object = $filter('filter')(studies, function (d) {return d.nodeRef === "56e3382b-9a76-48ee-9c14-907e71b7a184";})[0];
        console.log(single_object);
      return {
        all: function(){
          return studies;
        }
    };
    })
```

So as you can see I do a get request for a json file which contains objects with attributes "nodeRef" happens to be an attribute. I want to filter out a specific object based on its noderef matched. Currently the console.log returns "undefined" I think it is perhaps because it gets called before the json file is even loaded. I would really appreciate it if someone could provide a solution.

Comment: Put your filter logic inside the `get` callback.

Comment: how do I do that? Well I do want to get the entire json file since I need it for other operations as well and after that I want to perform the filter.

Answer (score 1):

You are performing an asynchronous request and firing the filter before the server's response, so that is why you are getting `undefined`, because at that point, you are applying a filter to an empty array.

You should move your filter call inside the `success` block to make it works as you want:

var app = angular.module('starter.services', [])

```
.factory('Studies',function($http,$filter){
    var studies = [];
    $http.get("studies.json").success(
            function(data){
                //studies = data;
                angular.copy(data, studies);
                single_object = filter("56e3382b-9a76-48ee-9c14-907e71b7a184");
                console.log(single_object);
            }
        );
  function filter(node) {
    if (studies.length > 0) {
      return $filter('filter')(studies, function (d) {return d.nodeRef === node;})[0];
    }
  }
  return {
    all: function(){
      return studies;
    },
    filtered: filter
};
})
```

Comment: well here is the thing I don't want to perform the filter just once during the callback. What if I want to run the filter function on the JSON array multiple times from my controller? which is why I was thinking of writing another return function like all called get: function(noderef) that the controller can call to return a specific object by noderef match

Comment: check out my answer that implements promises. You can run the filter using the .then() function in your controller

Comment: @user1585869, check my updated answer. Now it creates a function that can be called from outside. You only need to be sure that elements are loaded, if not, it will return false. But may be you can assume they will be ready at the time of calling the function from outside.

Comment: So if I want to call a particular node object from my controller to this service something like $scope.x = Studies.get("noderef_string") How do I do that?

Comment: .filtered("noderef_string") instead .get("noderef_string").

Answer (score 0):

You are right the console shows "undefined" because studies hasn't been populated after the ajax request yet. Move the filter and console log into the .success function:

```
$http.get("studies.json").success(
            function(data){
                //studies = data;
                angular.copy(data, studies);
                single_object = $filter('filter')(studies, function (d)  {return d.nodeRef === "56e3382b-9a76-48ee-9c14-907e71b7a184";})[0];
                console.log(single_object);
            }
        );
```

Also, I think you need a promise here to update studies when it is complete. Check out [Angular $q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

You would return the promise, and then resolve it inside the $http.success function, like this:
     var deferred = $q.defer();
    .factory('Studies',function($http,$q,$filter){

```
    var studies = [];
    $http.get("studies.json").success(
            function(data){
                //studies = data;
                angular.copy(data, studies);
                //At this point you can filter data as required, or not at all. I would suggest returning the entire JSON response and not filtering here at all, let the controllers filter the data as needed to maintain a layer of separation between controller and service.

                deferred.resolve(studies);
            }
        );

  return {
    all: function(){
      return deferred.promise;
    }
};
//In your controller, or wherever else...
Studies.all().then(function(studies){ //this will fire when everything is all done. The studies variable is a full JSON object returned from the server (See deferred.resolve() in the service class). Filter here accordingly:
$scope.studies = $filter('filter')(studies, function (d) {return d.nodeRef === "56e3382b-9a76-48ee-9c14-907e71b7a184";})[0];
})
```

Comment: from my controller can I do something like this: '$scope.studies = Studies.all(); $scope.x = Studies.get("56e3382b-9a76-48ee-9c14-907e71b7a184");' I will define a get function under return in the service that runs the filter. Will that work?

Comment: you still have the use the promise pattern: Studies.all().then(function(response){ $scope.studies=response; //And anything else you want to do to $scope.studies here});

Comment: Studies.all().then(function(studies){ //this will fire when everything is all done
}) Say if I want to return my entire studies json array how do I do that?

Comment: I've updated my answer to show returning the full JSON response then filtering in the controller, with comments

Comment: Alright what if I want to access the whole json data. Will something like Studies.all().then(function(payload){ $scope.studies = payload.data;
}); work?

Comment: Yep it should, double check your payload return value to make sure it has a .data property. But besides that you should be good to go.